# Django get pk row if pk is found in queryset filter

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I have the current table example :
[image]

I know how to get the rows where the ID is found in :

```
result_query_1 = models_contacts.objects.filter(company_members_id__icontains= str(pk)+";")

result_query_2 = (here I would like the row of the ID used for the previous query if a match is found)
```

But I would like to go one step further and also get the row **of the ID** in another queryset (depending on the first one matches).

For example :

If **id 1** is found in company_members_id :

result_query_1 = row N°2 (addidas) + row N°4 (Jordan)

**and**

result_query_2 = row N°1 (Nike)

I was thinking of using a for loop but I don't Know how to do this in Django.

Maybe there is a simpler / better way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but, is this what you are looking for?: `result_query_2 = models_contacts.objects.get(id=pk) if result_query_1.exists() else None`

Comment: It seems to be a solution but it returns : models_contacts object (2) in my HTML template and it's impossible to iterate

Comment: if you want a queryset also for result_query_2 use filter instead of get: `result_query_2 = models_contacts.objects.filter(id=pk) if result_query_1.exists() else None`

Comment: Ok it's working, just had to add .values(). Please make it an answer and i'll give you the vote. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer thanks to Igor Moraru in the comments :

```
 result_query_2 = models_contacts.objects.filter(id=pk).values() if result_query_1.exists() else None
```